# Can I back up my Xen-based VPS Remotely?

Tags: vps, xen

I have a Xen-based VPS instance of Ubuntu Server 12.04. I'd like to maintain my own offsite image of my install. The vendor does offer a variety of backup options for additional costs. I'm doing an inexpensive snapshot option, but would feel safe if I could clone the environment. I'm only using about 8 GB right now and I have good bandwidth on my site. What is an option for imaging this?

Comment: What version of Xen do they use?  If it's Xen Cloud Platform, you could set that up on a spare PC and clone the VPS there - it's free and doesn't need fancy pants virtualisation options unless you're looking to run Winders.

Comment: Assuming I install XCP on a spare machine, question is how do I get the VPS down to it? Is there an equivalent of VMWare converter that would aid this process? Also, I have an eSXI setup here, so question is whether there's a way to meld this all together and get my XCP from the VPS provider to be runnable on eSXI?

Comment: P.S. tried vCenter Converter Standalone and it says "unsable to detect disks or volumes of source mahince. Make sure that the source is a supported Linux distribution."

Comment: You should be able to write directly to the virtual disk from dom0 by going `ssh user@host.of.vps.com sudo dd if=/dev/of/root-device | dd of=/path/to/virtual/disk` - I haven't tried this myself but I don't see why it wouldn't work unless XCP doesn't have the ssh client. (replace path names as relevant and omit sudo if you're logging in as root)

Comment: Forgive my greenness on this...I am able to SSH to my VPS and am able to see into /dev from terminal. I'm unclear as to what my "if" should be. What would you need from me to be more specific about the path? Also, how would I formulate to the "of" if I want to write the resulting file to my remote machine? or should I just put this on the server and retrieve later?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux everything is a file.
So there is no need for an image here.

I would suggest to use `rsync`  to replicate your file systems.